# Как преобразовать Bitmap в Image?

Tags: c++, winapi, gdi+

Вот код:

```
VOID OnPaint(HDC hdc)
{
    // for flicker-free
    HDC memdc = CreateCompatibleDC(hdc);
    HBITMAP membm = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hdc, w, h);
    SelectObject(memdc, membm);

    Graphics    g(memdc);

    g.SetSmoothingMode(SmoothingModeAntiAlias);

    Bitmap b(L"file3.png");

    b.SetPixel(10, 10, Color(255, 255, 0));

    CachedBitmap cb(&b, &g);

    g.DrawCachedBitmap(&cb, 0, 0);

    // for flicker-free
    BitBlt(hdc, 0, 0, w, h, memdc, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    DeleteObject(membm);
    DeleteDC(memdc);
}
```

Вот, что тут происходит:

1. Итак, тут создаётся Bitmap, загружаемый из файла:

   ```
   Bitmap b(L"file3.png");
   ```
2. Тут я изменяю пиксель в координатах (10; 10)

   ```
   b.SetPixel(10, 10, Color(255, 255, 0));
   ```
3. Тут я рисую Bitmap с помощью Graphics.

   ```
   g.DrawCachedBitmap(&cb, 0, 0);
   ```

   ...но он умеет рисовать только CachedBitmap, а не обычный Bitmap, поэтому я создаю этот самый CachedBitmap до этого:

   ```
   CachedBitmap cb(&b, &g);
   g.DrawCachedBitmap(&cb, 0, 0);
   ```

И вот в чём проблема: `g.DrawCachedBitmap(&cb, 0, 0);` не может изменить размер изображения, а я хочу развернуть его на весь экран. Мне нужно преобразовать Bitmap в Image, но нигде я не могу найти способ для этого. Как это сделать?

Comment: Вместо BitBlt StretchBlt?  Или нужна растяжка с качеством гдиплюса?

Comment: `Bitmap` наследует от `Image`, так что преобразовывать ничего не надо, можно использовать прям так. Далее, у всех С функций WinAPI необходимо проверять возвращаемое значение, особенно у `DeleteObject` и `DeleteDC`. Тут скорее всего получаете утечку ресурсов.

Answer (score -1):

Для преобразования `Bitmap` в `Image` от GDI+ можно использовать конструктор класса `Image`, который принимает указатель на объект `Bitmap`.

В вашем коде можно заменить строку:

```
CachedBitmap cb(&b, &g);
```

на следующую строку:

```
Image image(&b, TRUE);
```

Теперь переменная image является экземпляром класса Image и вы можете использовать её в методах Graphics, например:

```
g.DrawImage(&image, 0, 0, w, h);
```

Здесь мы используем метод DrawImage для отображения изображения на всю область рисования с помощью аргументов `x`, `y`, `width` и `height`.